# Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'xyz' is blocked because of many connection errors;

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
$con1 = mysql_connect("xxx", "yyy", "zzz",'xyz');

$data = mysql_query("SELECT department_name,id,status FROM xyz.department");
$values = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
  echo  $row['department_name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row['department_name']); }
```

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'xyz' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hi.php

I am using Xampp Server.

Comment: And which script do you use to produce this error?

Comment: database connection $con1 = mysql_connect("xxx", "yyy", "zzz","xyz");

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your **full** and **real** code! (You can indeed use pseudo data for the connection)

Comment: now check edited question .

Comment: Is this your entire code? Also could it be that you have multiple connections? Since the name of the connection is `$con1`? Also where do you close the connection? Add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` at the top of your file(s) and tell us if you get any errors

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'xyz' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in C:\xampp\hi.php 
Could not connect : Host 'xyz' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Comment: Try just to restart your MySQL server. Or use this `FLUSH HOSTS;` In your input query browser in phpmyadmin

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run:

mysqladmin flush-hosts

Against your MySQL server.. or restart it will work also.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blocked-host.html